# Fixing 2 rows that aren't originally at the top to stick at the top of the page when scrolled down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not exactly sure if the title explains it well but here's a little abstract from the page I am currently writing

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%">

<div class="row" style="height: 50px; "> the navigation bar </div>
<div class="row" style="height: 20px; "> important section </div>
<div class="row" style="height: 20px; "> some info </div>
<div class="row" style="height: 30px; "> important section </div>
<div class="row" style="height: 150px; "> content </div>

</div>
```

I would really like the two important sections (rows 2 and 4) to stick at the top of the page when a user scrolls down, so that they together become some sort of a navigation panel while the user is browsing content

I looked through a few examples that involve the "fixed" class of Bootstrap but I am not sure how it can help

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Tried http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the window is scrolled, you need to add & remove a fixed positioning.

Check out this fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku8bL06n/1/)

Something like this should give you an idea of how to achieve what you are looking for.

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80) {
        $(".important").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        $(".important").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.sticky {  
position: fixed;  
width: 100%;  
left: 0;  
top: 0;  
z-index: 100;  
border-top: 0;  
}
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;  

var stickyNav = function(){  
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
$('.nav').addClass('sticky');  
}
else {  
$('.nav').removeClass('sticky');   
}  
};  
stickyNav();  

$(window).scroll(function() {  
stickyNav();  
});  
});
```

Comment: I like this one because it uses offset().top to determine exactly when to switch to fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Sticky](http://stickyjs.com/). It's an pretty awesome script that doesn't require much thinking. Elements just stick to the top once the browser is scrolled down to them.

So, you don't have to specify an exact pixel value at which the element sticks, it just works automatically.